# First name Constantin or Constantine?

Tags: names

Which is correct: "Constantin" or "Constantine"? I also encountered in texts "Konstantin" and "Kostantine". Or else is another spelling preferred?

Comment: In English texts, it's ususally _Constantine_.

Comment: But if a direct transliteration from a foreign language (say, Russian) is possible, it may be rendered *Konstantin*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Roman emperor Flavius Valerius Aurelius Constantinus Augustus is generally rendered as *Constantine* in English, and this form is almost certainly the most common.

For personal names, however, there is no single "correct" spelling, as personal names are not regulated in most English-speaking countries. *Constantin* is the French and Romanian spelling, for example, so Constantines from those countries will retain that spelling. The same name transliterated (but not anglicized) from the Cyrillic for a Ukrainian or Russian is often *Konstantin* or *Konstantyn*. You can also turn up *Constantyn* and *Constantyne*, and probably other variations as well.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the dialect.

My grandfather’s name is Constantine, When my Great Grandfather came over from Greece it was Constantine as well.

If you go by other variants you will see something along:

Constans, Constan, Constant, Constanc, Constance, Consten, Constens, Constense, Constence, Constanse, Constane, Constene, Constante, Contans, Contan, Contant, Contance, Conten, Contens, Contense, Contence, Contanse, Contane, and Contene.

There are plenty more as well, but basically it all depends on the country and dialect. Also family names, and personal names throw the name of how it should be spelled, etc throw logic out the window.